# Clojure database interaction - application design/approach

Tags: database, clojure

I hope this question isn't too general or doesn't make sense.

I'm currently developing a basic application that talks to an SQLite database, so naturally I'm using the `clojure.java.jdbc` library ([link](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc)) to interact with the DB.

The trouble is, as far as I can tell, the way you insert data into the DB using this library is by simply passing a map (e.g. `{:id 1 :name "stackoverflow"}` and a table name (e.g. `:website`)

The thing that that I'm concerned about is how can I make this more robust in the wider context of my application? What I mean by this is when I write data to the database and retrieve it, I want to use the same formatted map EVERYWHERE in the application, so from the data access layer (returning or passing in maps) all the way up to the application layer where it works on the data and passes it back down again.

What I'm trying to get at is, is there an 'idiomatic' clojure equivalent of JavaBeans?

The problem I'm having right now is having to repeat myself by defining maps manually with column names etc - but if I change the structure of my table in the DB, my whole application has to be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there really isn't such a library. There are various systems that make it easier to write queries, but not AFAIK, anything that "fixes" your data objects.

I've messed around trying to write something like you propose myself but I abandoned the project since it became very obvious very quickly that this is not at all the right thing to do in a clojure system (and actually, I tend to think now that the approach has only very limited use even in languages that have really "fixed" data structures).

Issues with the clojure collection system:

- All the map access/alteration functions are really functional. That
  means that alterations on a map always return a new object, so it's
  nearly impossible to create a forcibly fixed map type that's also
  easy to use in idiomatic clojure.

General conceptual issues:

- Your assumption that you can *"use the same formatted map EVERYWHERE
  in the application, so from the data access layer (returning or
  passing in maps) all the way up to the application layer where it
  works on the data and passes it back down again"* is wrong if your
  system is even slightly complex. At *best*, you can use the map from
  the DB up to the UI in some simple cases, but the other way around is
  pretty much always the wrong approach.
- Almost every query will have its own result row "type"; you're
  probably not going to be able to re-use these "types" across queries
  even in related code.
- Also, forcing these types on the rest of the program is probably
  binding your application **more** strictly to the DB schema. If your
  business logic functions are sane and well written, they should only
  access as much data as they need and no more; they should probably
  not use the same data format everywhere.

My serious answer is; don't bother. Write your DB access functions for the kinds of queries you want to run, and let those functions check the values moving in and out of the DB as much detail as you find comforting. Do not try to forcefully keep the data coming from the DB "the same" in the rest of your application. Use assertions and pre/post conditions if you want to check your data format in the rest of the application.

Comment: Excellent reply, thanks for that! So the suggestion is to keep schema specific stuff specific to the DB layer and that should do any transformations on any data it receives? The rest of the application should refrain from coupling to the DB?

Answer (score 2):

Clojure favour the concept of `Few data structure and lots of functions to work on these few data structures`. There are few ways to create new data structure (which I guess internally uses the basic data structures) like defrecord etc. But again if you are able to use them that won't really solve the problem that **DB schema changes should effect the code less** as you will eventually have to go through layers to remove/add the effects of the schema changes, because anywhere you are reading/creating that data that needs to be changed